# algorithms for fast set operations

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

i have sets in the form of (a,b) as

(2,4) (1,3) (4,5) (1,2)

Given a list like <2,1> i want to find all sets in the list which have 2 or 1 as the first element, in this case (2,4) (1,3) (1,2) and get the maximum(b) from them...for this case it would be 4.

how best to do this as fast as possible?

my first approach was, get all a's from the sets and do an intersection on them with <2,1> and then do a max of all b's in the set....but this would not scale well with large sets.
also, we can change the structure of data as well if needed or do any preprocessing if it helps..

im using plain javascript, and i have these as arrays of Tuples or object with 2 properties int , int

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: a set is unordered ... I dont get it. which language are you talking about? do you mean tuples? or a set that consists of tuples?

Comment: @PatrickArtner .. i updated the question, im using plain javascript and using arrays for representing data...hope it helps

Comment: Hint: can easily be solved in Ө(n), where n is the number of (a, b) tuples you have. One iteration suffices, can also be done with one iteration over the entire list and one iteration over all "filtered" tuples.

Comment: So go for it... why do you think your method will not be fast? You name suggest you *code*, so let's see it. Note that in JS a Set is not what you are referring to. Also tuple is not a separate concept in JS -- that would be an array.

Comment: If you need to reuse that I would use a dictionary with key f.e. 2 and a list of datatuples after it. You ned 1 pass to insert all into a dict, after that its O(1) to get to the right datapoints. If you sorted the datapoints according to criteria when adding into the list (some more O(...)) of the dict its O(1) again to get the first/last one choosing the correct structures. Else you need to max() ofter the partition that belongs to the key which is O(however many are in it). You have more memory but faster access. If you need it once, got through it once, test for key, test for > and done.

Comment: Voting to close this question because it doesn't provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AaditMShah, to be fair, that is not a reason to vote to close, but to downvote.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/findmax-12345

Answer (score 0):

Here are two straightforward ways, one using a for loop and another one using reduce.

```js
function findMax (list,filter) {
   let  max = 0; 
   for (let [key,val] of list) {
        if (filter.includes (key))
            max = Math.max (max, val)
   }
   return max;
}

function findMax2 (list, filter) {
     const toMax = (max,[key,val]) => Math.max (filter.includes(key) * val, max);
     return list.reduce (toMax, 0);
}

const data = [
  [2, 4],
  [1, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [1, 2]
]

const filter = [1, 2];

console.log(findMax(data, filter))
console.log(findMax2(data, filter))
```

Comment: You really should initialise `e = false` to avoid confusion. Also you can directly do `for (const [c, d] of list)`, no need to make an extra `ele` variable to destructure.

Comment: Btw, if `vals` is an array, just use `e = vals.includes(c)`; and if its a set, just use `e = vals.has(c)`